# Updating an SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. The two tables have more than one column in common. One of these columns has unique value. One column is there in one table which is not present in other table. How can write a query which can insert that column data from one table into other table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ALTER TABLE` query to add the column to the second table.

```
ALTER TABLE Your_Table ADD NewFieldName NewFieldType
```

Then just copy the data from one table to another.

Comment: Yes i know that way to add new column into table.But copy means what "row by row". I have 1000 rows. Any query you know."Row by row " will take time and may be error.